# I have a problem with a value of type never in one iteration, then I try to do push using the variable i

Tags: angular, typescript

This is the part of the code:

```
// Calculate total hours
for (let i:number = 0; i < this.bars; i++) {
  this.totalBars.push(i);
}
```

this is the error:

let i: number

Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2345)

Comment: Can u post the type of totalBars array

Answer (score 0):

While declaring this.totalBars variable assign it with empty array and run again.

```
this.totalBars = [];
```

By default if value is not assigned never will be set to the variable

Hope this will help you